# variable not redefining jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I've created my first function in jQuery. Now I have problems redefining a variable in my function.

`fileValid` is not defining to what I need it to. As you can see in my ajax call, `if(result=="true"){fileValid = false; }else{ fileValid = true;}`. Here `fileValid` is not being redefined and stays it's default value.

Here is my code:

```
(function( $ ) {
    $.fn.checkFile = function(file){

        var fileValid = true;

        var form_data = new FormData();
        form_data.append("op", "235353")
        form_data.append("file", file);

        $.ajax({
          url:"ajax/scripts/message.php?w=<?php echo $workspace_id?>",
          type:"POST",
          data:form_data,
          contentType: false,
          processData:false,
          success:function(data){
              var result = $.trim(data);
              if(result=="true"){fileValid = false; }else{ fileValid = true;}
              }
          });   

        return fileValid;    
    }
}( jQuery ));
```

Comment: Variable to be global need to stay out any function, and there's not out, try to put the `var fileValid = true;`, before `(function( $ ) {`.

Comment: @user3294463, Err, what do you mean by redefining fileValid? Your code doesn't seem to have any errors. Also, fileValid is not global. You can make it global by defining it outside of the function.

Comment: `var fileValid` is in `$.fn.checkFile = function(file){`

Comment: If you want to globalize `fileValid` you would remove the `var` keyword. What I think you meant is "redefining a parent scoped variable"

Comment: @Austin, if he removes the `var`, doesn't he have problem with `"use strict";` ?

Comment: @Austi yea I meant that . Sorry for the confusion

Comment: `Now I have problems redefining...` What is your problem? Please edit question and clearly state a question, so it can be useful for others.

Comment: @GuilhermeLopes yes it would fail under `"use strict";` I was just answering the question "how to globalize a variable". Should have added a note that global's are usually a bad idea.

Comment: @kebs updated question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ajax is async, so you can't *return* its results like that. Use callbacks:

```
$.fn.checkFile = function(file, complete){
...
success: function(data){
    var result = $.trim(data);
    complete(result=="true" ? true : false);
});
```

Or even:

```
$.fn.checkFile = function(file, valid, invalid){
...
success: function(data){
    var result = $.trim(data);
    if (result=="true") { valid(); } else { invalid(); }
});
```

Now, if you have a global variable `fileValid` you can redefine it like:

```
$(...).checkFile("myFile", function() {
    fileValid = true;
});
```

Comment: `complete(result=="true" ? true : false);` is throwing an error saying `complete is not a function` :(

Comment: @user3284463 did you used `function(file, complete)` this signature?

Comment: Yeap, it now looks like this `$.fn.checkFile = function(file, complete){`